# How to made Paging base on SortedList class

Tags: c#, paging, sortedlist

Hello i have method returned SortedList object
I need to do Paging

`SortedList output = this.GetSearchResults(SearchQuery.QueryString, se);
ViewBag.ResultSearch = output;`

How to make equivalent example in linq

....Skip(100).Take(5);

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since a `SortedList` does not implement `IEnumerable<T>`(unlike [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx)) you need to cast it to a type to get an `IEnumerable<T>`.

For example:

```
var paged = sl.Cast<Object>()
              .Skip(100)
              .Take(5);
```